# Schengen visa for minor child travelling with grandparents

Tags: visas, schengen, paperwork, children, minors

I am planning to visit my younger daughter in Switzerland in August. I want to take my elder daughter's 6-year-old child with me. The hitch is that my daughter is separated from her husband and is staying with me now. Her husband may not sign the mandatory declaration form of the other parent required for issuance of Schengen visa. Without that, how would get the visa?

Comment: Depending on where you live, it may be illegal to take the child abroad against the wishes of *one* legal guardian if there is a dispute. A judgement by a divorce court may help.

Answer (score 1):

Under the current circumstances, it is unlikely that a Schengen visa would be granted to the minor child in the absence of consent of both parents. There’s no workaround: it affords protection to both the child and the parents.

The application process requires that, if the child is traveling alone (accompanied by you but neither parent), you would have to present certified parental consent by both parents. If the child travels with only one parent, the other parent must produce the notarized/certified consent, and a copy of the absent parent’s passport may also be requested. If only one parent has guardianship of the minor, the relevant court documents must be presented. Some consular authorities require that both parents sign in the presence of a consular official.

Comment: "unlikely that a Schengen visa would not be granted" means that the visa will probably be granted. I think you mean the opposite.

Comment: @phoog TY; multiple edits, my own :)